# iOS CGContextAddArc and different screen resolutions

Tags: ios, graphics

My app draws a graph showing a small circle as part of a weight & balance calculation, using the code below.  This all works perfectly on an iPad 2, but the circle fails to display on other (higher resolution) iPad devices.  I have increased the size of the circle x 10 but it still doesn't display on higher resolution devices...  The line components of the graph (the w & b boundaries) display perfectly on all devices.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [circlePointsArray count]; i++) {
        CGPoint circlePoint = [[circlePointsArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddArc(context, circlePoint.x, circlePoint.y, 3, -M_PI, M_PI, 1);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    }
```

I am lost with this one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting M_PI to a float will solve the problem. The fact that CGContextAddArc takes CGFloat arguments, and CGFloat is defined differently on 32 bit versus 64 bit platforms. on 32 bit, it's a float, on 64 bit it's a double.

Try the below code -

```
CGContextAddArc(context, 100., 100., 10., -(float)M_PI, (float)M_PI, YES);
```